# PS4 error code ‘’’CE-31117-3’’’

Tags: ps4, controllers

Can anyone tell me what to do about this code? Comes up on my daughters ps4 when trying to use wireless controller. Had the WiFi connect issue so since there’s not a good fix for that we hooked up a LAN. Still can’t connect the wireless controller even with usb cable it just flashes. When we check device settings that code comes up but I can’t find anything on it. Help please! If I hear her complain about it again I’m gonna go crazy!

Comment: If [this](https://us.community.sony.com/s/question/0D54O00005wC7jfSAC/my-ps4-lost-power-in-rest-mode-now-the-controllers-wont-reconnect-bluetooth-says-error-code-ce-31117-dash-73?language=en_US) is anything to go off of, you might need to contact [PS support](https://support.us.playstation.com).

Comment: Thank you for that! I have been searching but not found that post. You are awesome!

Comment: If they give you an answer that works, be sure to come back and post it here so other's can benefit from your knowledge.